# Mac OS 10.5.1 - Illustrator close by itself suddenly

Tags: mac, adobe-illustrator, adobe-cs4

We have a Mac user in our business and she is using Illustrator CS4. The issue now is that program close by itself without warning. I am wondering what could be the problem but I'm not a geek with mac.

Basicaly, when she opens a new artwork, she works on it for like 30 minutes and then, illustrator shutsdown. I have the error message but it's kinda long...

---

Error message:
http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/188420/Details-probleme-doc.html

**Computer specs:**

Model: MacPro3,1, BootROM MP31.006C.B02,

- 8 processors, Quad-Core Intel Xeon, 2.8 GHz,
- 4GB Ram
- Graphics: kHW_ATIrv630Item, ATI Radeon HD 2600, spdisplays_pcie_device, 256 MB

  - Memory Module: DIMM Riser B/DIMM 1, 1
    GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz
  - Memory Module: DIMM Riser B/DIMM 2, 1 GB,
    DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz
  - Memory Module:
    DIMM Riser A/DIMM 1, 1 GB, DDR2
    FB-DIMM, 667 MHz
  - Memory Module: DIMM
    Riser A/DIMM 2, 1 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM,
    667 MHz
- Bluetooth: Version 2.1.0f8, 2 service, 0 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
- Network Service: Ethernet 1, Ethernet, en0
- PCI Card: ATI Radeon HD 2600, display, Slot-1
- Serial ATA Device: WDC WD3200AAJS-41VWA0, 298,09 GB
- Parallel ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-7170A
- USB Device: Keyboard Hub, Apple, Inc., high_speed, 500 mA
- USB Device: Apple Optical USB Mouse, Primax Electronics, low_speed, 100 mA
- USB Device: Apple Keyboard, Apple, Inc, low_speed, 100 mA
- USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, Apple, Inc., full_speed, 500 mA
- FireWire Device: built-in_hub, unknown_value, unknown_speed

---

Thanks for the hand!!!

Regards,

David

Comment: I'd never download anything from megaupload. Please use something like http://pastebin.com/ instead.

Comment: No worry, I don't put crap on this great site.

Comment: Pastebin link: http://pastebin.ca/1775828

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this similar issue with Illustrator. The only solution I found was to create another user account and run Illustrator from there.

You can also try a full uninstall / reinstall of all Adobe applications.

When I contacted Adobe, they gave me a link to [this article](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403878.html) in their support section.

Comment: I will read this now and come back to you!THanks!!